# Communicate cs->js wp8 InvokeCustomScript chariotsolutions

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-phone-8, nfc, ndef

I tried https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc to read NFC tag under WP8 (VS 2013) on Nokia 735 but I failed.

Problem occures when nfc\platforms\wp8\Plugins\com.chariotsolutions.nfc.plugin\NfcPlugin.cs try to communicateafter tapping nfc with javasript function fireNfcTagEvent() through:

```
ScriptCallback script = new ScriptCallback("fireNfcTagEvent", new string[] { "ndef", JsonHelper.Serialize(tag) });
this.InvokeCustomScript(script, false);
```

I added alert("1") at the beginning of function fireNfcTagEvent() but it never pop ups...

how can I fix it? how can I communicate with JS properly?

Moreover during building process there is (possibly not crutial) a warning:

> Plugins\com.chariotsolutions.nfc.plugin\NfcPlugin.cs(184,12): warning CS0612: 'WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands.BaseCommand.InvokeCustomScript(WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.ScriptCallback, bool)' is obsolete [C:\Users\xxx\Documents\xxx\nfc\platforms\wp8\Nfc.csproj]

My question of course is about properly executing `fireNfcTagEvent`; not about warning during building process. I'm looking for any help.